# Error when trying to send text to application with Pywinauto: AttributeError

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

I am using Pywinauto to automate some interaction steps with an application that opens during a browser login session.

Lets call the application program.exe. It is actually a Chrome Extension that opens and prompts for a password.

```
import pywinauto as pwa
from pywinauto import application
from pywinauto import keyboard

app = application.Application()
app = app.Connect(path=r"C:\path\program.exe")                 
win.Part.Click() #not completely sure why i do this
app['Insert password']['Edit'].send('password')
```

It seems that I am able to connect to the program, but when I try to send text to the program I get an error. When i run the above this error occurs:

```
AttributeError: Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'send' were found (typo?)
```

If i replace this:

```
app['Insert password']['Edit'].send('password')
```

With this:

```
app['Insert password'].SendKeys.send('password')
```

I get this error:

```
MatchError: Could not find 'SendKeys' in 'dict_keys(['Insert password for MyName:Static', 'Static', 'Insert password for MyName:Edit', 'Edit', 'OK', 'OKButton', 'Button', 'Button0', 'Button1', 'Button2', 'Cancel', 'CancelButton', 'Insert password for MyName:Static0', 'Insert password for MyName:Static1', 'Insert password for MyName:Static2', 'Insert password for MyName:', 'Static0', 'Static1', 'Static2'])'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There is no method `send` for any of the controls. `SendKeys` is not a method, but a function inside module `keyboard` so the correct usage is `keyboard.SendKeys('password')`.
- But method `.type_keys('password')` puts the control into focus and then does the same as `keyboard.SendKeys`. You may need to use `with_spaces=True` if password contains spaces. Special symbols like `%` must be escaped so: `{%}`. This method is powerful because it supports hot key combinations with Alt, Shift, Ctrl etc. See [the docs about keyboard module](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.keyboard.html). Usage for your case:

  `app['Insert password']['Edit'].type_keys('password', with_spaces=True)`

---

- Method `.set_edit_text('password')` can be even more useful: it doesn't type keys char by char, but sends the whole raw text to the control (no support for special keys, just text). This method doesn't require the control to be in focus.